# Change value of asp drop down list to asterisk on change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have an asp drop down list with a VB.NET code file, created as so

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="txtPac1" cssclass="txtPAC" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" aria-required="true"/>
```

which is populated on page load by a function

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 9
    dropDown.Items.Add(i.ToString())
Next
```

When an option is selected, I want the text of the ddl to become an asterisk, but for the list to retain it's drop down items.

I tried using javascript like this:

```
$(document).on("change", "#<%=txtPac1.ClientID%>", function() {
    $(this).text("*");  
});
```

but it's just blanking the ddl and removing all options

Answer (score 1):

`this` refers to the `select` element, not the `option` element.

Use `$(this).find("option")` to select all the `options` of `select-input`

```
$(document).on("change", "#<%=txtPac1.ClientID%>", function() {
    $(this).find("option").text("*");  
});
```

Comment: That is closer to a solution that I had managed, but now it is changing all options of the ddl to *'s. Do you know of a way to change only what appears and leave the list as is? Thanks for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by _"text of the ddl"_ ? Are you referring to some Element ? Where is that element ?

Comment: @Rayon - My understanding is that he wants to show *** in the DropDownList box when the list is collapsed but still see the actual option text when the list is expanded.

Comment: Correct, but at the moment it is displaying the asterix in the collapsed ddl, but also changing every option of the ddl to an asterix